# How to prevent starting a new CSS column until necessary?

Tags: css

How can I have a fixed column layout but get the text to vertically fill out the columns before starting on the next. In other words (screenshot from chrome);

[image]

The trouble is, when I specify 5 columns it spreads even a single line that would fit perfectly into one column across as many as it can.

[image: not this]

I can't seem to get it to do the 'sensible' thing. I don't want to change the number of columns dynamically I want to be able to do this with pure CSS. Fill the first column up first before moving on to the second, and then third and so on.

Is it possible? Here's what I'm using so far;

```
.content{
-webkit-column-count: 5;
-moz-column-count: 5;
-ms-column-count: 5;
-o-column-count: 5;
column-count: 5;

-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;
-ms-column-gap: 20px;
-o-column-gap: 20px;
column-gap: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26NGr/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424088/css-column-breaks Answer #3 by Joe seems to address this. All the documentation I can find suggests that column breaking isn't well supported yet or that you should use a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's quite the same problem though. The issue with that approach is that it forces me to break the columns myself. I might as well just set the column count if I know where the breaks are supposed to go. http://jsfiddle.net/WhkK5/

Comment: I don't feel like that's what columns are really for. You're trying to flow text downward, after telling it to break into columns, hence the need for a wrapper. The renderer deems the column as "full", and breaks into another, especially when using a % width. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap your content in `<p>` or something similar and apply the `break-inside` to that, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/26NGr/1/

```css
.content p {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately that breaks the large text version.

Comment: Can you use javascript? I might be able to come up with a solution that would just add a class if the text is short enough.

Comment: I want to try and achieve it without JS if possible. I think the key to it is the columns need a height as per my other answer. If I can get the height set correctly I think it should work out of the box.

Comment: Hope you find an answer. I tried setting `min-height` and it seems like it just changes the `height` on all of the `.content` elements, not the `min-height`.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't get min-height to work either. I have an updated answer that seems to work tho. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can get it to sort of work with the following CSS;

```
column-fill:auto; /* not supported in chrome, but appears to be the default */
height:100px;
```

It doesn't work however with `%` sizes. I would have to use a fixed `px` size which I cannot do.

#### update

However, [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq4pm/) solution works with relative sizes and seems to work in latest Chrome, IE, FF and Safari.

Using the padding-bottom trick I managed to set a relative height for the `wrapper` container;

```
.wrapper {
    padding-bottom:10%; /* spacer - this is my relative height */
    background-color:lightblue;
    position:relative; /* abs coord stop here */
}
```

With this;

```
<h1>short test</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">
   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I can do this;

```
.content{
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    -ms-column-count: 5;
    -o-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;

    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -ms-column-gap: 20px;
    -o-column-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;

    column-fill:auto;

    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%; /* fill wrapper container */
    width:100%;

    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

The trade-off is that if I have too much content it will keep adding columns horizontally beyond the 5 I requested. It won't expand downwards, but I guess that actually makes sense.