# Text Wrapping with Zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to be able to wrap text if there is a resizing of the window, I know this can be done as there have been other questions similar to mine in SO. (I guess this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377376/how-to-get-textcolumns-to-auto-wrap-in-zurb-foundation-v3-2-5) would qualify )

I am using Foundation 4 (latest version) and the provided solution does not work; for example take a look at the following screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPhBU.jpg) which shows the result, computed CSS rules and actual page markup. It also shows that the strings of consecutive a's are not wrapped as they should. Any ideas on how to go about an correcting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a language. It is a CSS framework. Word wrapping techniques are same as CSS. try the code below.

```
.class
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but could you tell me why the previous solution did not work (the one provided in the other SO topic)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the align attribute. This allows the text to wrap.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
  <img align="right" src="http://placeimg.com/240/240/any">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero eligendi optio sed     numquam hic. Error repellendus in placeat officia alias sapiente facere asperiores accusamus quaerat ea voluptatibus commodi, pariatur, obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores nemo, illum mollitia quos delectus. Cupiditate deserunt ipsa esse a fuga, veniam, magnam, possimus reprehenderit commodi voluptate quaerat quisquam vel sed.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```