# how can I break column from heading?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the `column-count` css but when the single column is divided into three columns it's heading is on first column and the rest in another column

```
#xmap{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nP4je/)

**Question:** Can I force to break from heading? Here in my fiddle I want **headermenu**  to shift it from first to second column with css only?(without touching markup)

I have another choice to use `nth-child()` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nP4je/2/)

But this creates the space above of `footer-menu`. How can I truncate that space?

Comment: Possible duplicat [CSS column breaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424088/css-column-breaks)

Comment: column breaks? not worked....

Comment: One possibility is to use JavaScript to add the columns `max-height` to all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#xmap h2 {
  column-break-after: avoid;
}
```

and the vendor prefixed variants.

Comment: The heading "headermenu" is in the 2nd column for me without changing anything, but my answer should work.